# Android RuntimeException vs. OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I have developed a PhotoViewer application wihch simply lists the image files in external storages and shows them if the user wants to see one of them. My problem occurs when my thread drawing the thumbnails for the images.

If the count of images is less than about 500 it is ok for me and there is no issue but if the user has over 1000 images (it is quite possible) afters some drawing thumbs the memory usage exceeds the limit and I get OutOfMemory Exception.

I have tried to use bitmap.recycle() but this time I have faced with  using a recycled bitmap error (RuntimeException).  Could you suggest me a way to show more and more thumbnails (over 2000 maybe) for the images in external storages?

Comment: Perhaps you should only draw the images that will be seen on the screen, not to draw all the images. How do you display your images, in a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Your OutOfMemory problem will probably be resolved if you got recycle() working correctly. The RunTimeException will be an ImageView still trying to draw a bitmap which has been recycle, so you must ensure that nothing is using the bitmap before you recycle it.

You could also stop thumbnails being loaded whilst the ListView is being scrolled using a ListView.OnScrollListener - without this, if the user flings through the list, all intermediate rows that scroll past are still getting loaded.